Greater standing bag 100kg strike impact
Any video or move advices to make greater impact to standing bag 100kg or something almost double your size?
Kinetic strike is one of the method that I know of.
Prefer trying on standing bag or dead object instead trying on of real human.
100kg vs 65kg kinetic strike KO

The question asked is how to impact with greater force on a heavyweight punching bag.
The short answer is to study boxing. They've been doing punching right for a century at least. The level of skill at punching in an average boxing gym is very high relative to an average Asian martial arts school, in my opinion.
I want you to observe a video showing what a boxer with heavy hands looks like:
https://youtu.be/kN68W3oAOO4?si=DsPG08E_gGE5Ddbk
He didn't get that good overnight. He's a coach. It starts with having the right punch mechanics. Notice his body structure during each punch. To get the most power into the strike, his entire body must be connected throughout and especially at the moment the punch hits the bag. He gains power from his legs and waist. The wider apart his legs are, the stronger his punch. The wider he swings his arm, the stronger his punch.
But the key to it all is the connection of his entire body during the strike.
The video OP showed with the wing chun "kinetic striking" is also an example of full body mechanics. But during the strike in the video, notice it's also pushing, not just striking. Notice how the wing chun practitioner lunges forward while keeping the back leg planted in place, and upon making contact with the opponent, it unbalances his opponent and pushes him back. It's not a pure punch. That pushing motion is done with the whole body behind it, which sends his unbalanced opponent flying backwards. It can give the illusion that this is a very powerful punch.
Contrast that with the boxing video I linked to above. There's no pushing involved. It's all done with the punch itself. And yet, the entire body is behind the punch. That is demonstrating more power than the wing chun video OP linked to.
The wing chun "kinetic strike" may be very useful in some situations, don't get me wrong. It has its place. But just isolating the punching aspect of such a strike, it's not very powerful by itself. It is a combination of stepping in, connecting with an opponent, unbalancing the opponent, and then shoving (pushing) while punching. So it's not the same as a pure punch. The power here comes mostly from an unbalanced opponent being thrown backward. A skilled boxer's punch would maybe not throw someone backward, but it can do a lot more damage.
Hope that helps.

okok..i try single elbow strike then see can do similar thing.. The wing chun "kinetic strike" may be very useful in some situations --> it's useful if really too close contact that no space to do an arm swing punch.. i.e. when a guy try to molest a girl at a close contact

@whatsappcat The downside is that it relies on the opponent standing in a way that they are easily unbalanced from the push. If you draw a straight line between the heels, you push in the direction perpendicular to that line. Trouble is, that doesn't happen very often and can't be relied on. Secondly, the push itself is not going to do much damage. It merely gets them away from you, perhaps giving you an opportunity to run. But, don't expect huge distance. A push like this might just knock someone back a foot or two. Rather have powerful punches. Short range is no problem for boxers.

unbalanced from the push. --> agreed. I trained for escape and it (Wing Chun) was originally designed so during war time mainly for women to escape and not for MMA. Rather have powerful punches.--> My punch already reached 999 with some simple subconscious move, u can refer to Bruce 6 inch punch . I dont wanna injure anyone n get myself jailed ..aha.. so i practice push only. I dont swing that much by the way to have same effect. I dont posses much muscle as well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8DCH3AWbbw

@whatsappcat Well, the question was how to make a bigger impact on the punching bag. Pushing is different from impacting. The real question you should ask is which discipline has the most powerful punches. And while there are outliers, I read studies in the past indicating boxers on average produce more powerful punches than karate practitioners, for example. Wing Chun would be far behind, but for the reasons you mentioned.

why me Wing Chun ? because many secret techniques written in Chinese and can't even found using google .. many books was burned too during attack to Shaolin centuries back.. i just kinda interested into it and try to re-dig back what is left.. well, each martial arts got it's own strength and weakness. Lastly, it's just personal preference. If you have something marvelous, feel free to show ya here and me keen to know from other types of martial arts.

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/14976/how-can-just-128-shaolin-monks-defeated-a-10k-troops    may b is hyper kinetic strike ..hahahaha
