How can just 128 Shaolin monks defeated a 10k troops?

It was the 128 monks of the southern Shaolin temple who defeated the
army of Xilu over three months in 1673 without suffering a single
casualty. However, by doing so the monks had made enemies of those in
the Qing army and Qing court who were embarrassed by how easily the
Shaolin monks had succeeded where they had failed.

Shaolin History
There is a myth just 128 Shaolin monks defeated a 10k troops? How can?
What was the real story then as too many version ?

Considering that there's still question as to whether or not a southern Shaolin temple even existed, and given that martial arts histories are rife with tales of super-human and supernatural feats, I think something like this should just be seen as a nice story. And leave it at that.
Ask yourself if a collection of a hundred or so martial artists could take on an entire army of many thousands of people? And none of those martial artists were killed? Does that sound realistic?
Ask why there doesn't appear to be any documentation of these troops being killed in battle by a hundred or so martial artists? What external documentation exists of the event? None. You know, killing 10,000 soldiers in battle might have gotten some notice somewhere. It's a pretty big battle. It might have been documented. But it wasn't. Isn't that strange?
There are many more examples of this from martial arts folklore. In Hung Gar kung-fu, for example, the famous Wong Fei-Hung took on 30 gang members all at once and didn't get a scratch on him.
Why I was just 6 years old at the time when I had observed the way a spider attacks its prey. Not long after that, I was walking home from school one day, and a gang of many older, high school kids bullied me. So I remembered the spider and quickly defeated all 20 kids at the same time. Four of them died. I ate them. The end. Haha.
Hope that helps.

And arguably, with a good choke point, it could be done. Zero casualties would seem unlikely, but not impossible. But yeah, this one seems more lore than history, at best having an origin where a small group was able to convince the army that defeating them would involve too many casualties in a pitched battle (and admittedly. it didn't turn out well for them in the legend, either, where the army came back and burned down the monastary from afar with incendiaries...)

@Steve Weigand as a martial artist, we train our mind also. one of it known as self control. The battle won may due to negotiation, confrontation, influencing, etc. No fight for win win is the best win. True monk normally equipped with psychology knowledge or may brain washed those xilu gang without a fight or they overly compassion to protect the yet causing the destruction of Shaolin. The largest original Chinese triads or known as Hong Men as the descendant of Xilu still exist today.

https://brief.kharon.com/updates/chinese-crime-boss-broken-tooth-built-business-network-after-prison-stint/

From the same article (bolding mine):

Both these versions of the legend of Pai Mei come from inheritors of Bak Mei Kung Fu yet are very different from each other. Accounts of the Bak Mei and the Five Great Kung Fu Masters are many and varied. The latter account names the Shaolin traitor as Ma Ning-Yee rather than Bak Mei, though that detail was omitted for reasons of length. In other versions, Bak Mei and Ma Ning-Yee both betray Shaolin, sometimes joined by Fung Do-Duk. Still other versions say that “Bak Mei” is a nickname for either Ma Ning-Yee or Fung Do-Duk. For that matter, the legend of Bak Mei may have no basis in historical fact at all, and come solely from wuxia novels like Wan Nian Qing. The legends are particularly confused because some temples were burned down repeatedly, including after the time of Bak Mei.


This info coming from a myth story or known as Legend Xilu. No proper documentation was found due to underground society that anti Qing Dynasty during that time and it's meant to be a secret.
However, many wars won without a single damages which thru negotiation and communication. Martial arts taught about wisdom and peace too other than marvelous powerful fist. It's matter of wisdom or power alone.

The student pondered the master's words, feeling the weight of their
wisdom. He realized that true strength was not just about physical
prowess, but also about understanding when to use it and, more
importantly, when to refrain. The master continued, "In cultivating
both your skills and your spirit, you find balance. Peace is the
ultimate goal, but one must be prepared to defend it." The student
nodded slowly, gaining a newfound respect for the delicate harmony his
master spoke of. He decided then and there to dedicate himself not
only to becoming a skilled fighter but also to nurturing a peaceful
heart. With every lesson, he would strive to embody the principles of
both strength and serenity, understanding that in the unity of these
two qualities lay true wisdom and power.



This honestly does not answer your question.
